# Check legal characters by regular expression but with unexpected result

Tags: javascript, regex

I have defined some characters which are legal to use.

```
var reg= /[-!*() ~{}'<>._a-zA-Z0-9]/g
```

In order to test the regular expression's correctness, I write a test case as below:

```
var arr= ["-", ".", "!", "~", "*", "(", ")", "'", "_","<",">"];  
for(var i=0 ;i < arr.length;i++)                                                 
{                                                                                
 console.log( arr[i] +"  " + reg.test(arr[i]));                               
}
```

But the output from the `console.log()` is `true/false/true/false`...

It's also very strange when I type  `reg.test(.);`
The output is also the same: `true/false/true/false`. (Iterative)

Can anyone tell me the reason and give me a correct regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when a global regex is used multiple times, the `lastIndex` property gets updated.

[**MDN:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

> As with exec() (or in combination with it), test() called multiple
>   times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past
>   the previous match.

So, you need to remove the global flag. It doesn't affect the result in anyway, as it still returns false when the *first* non-allowed character is encountered.

Comment: Is this reg expression correct? Can I switch the characters order in the regular expression like `/[-a-zA-Z0-9!*() ~{}'<>._]/`?
And what is side effect if I remove global flag?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `g` (*global*) flag.

```
> var reg= /[-!*() ~{}'<>._a-zA-Z0-9]/;
undefined
> var arr= ["-", ".", "!", "~", "*", "(", ")", "'", "_","<",">"];
undefined
> for(var i=0 ;i < arr.length;i++)
... {
... console.log( arr[i] +"  " + reg.test(arr[i]));
... }
-  true
.  true
!  true
~  true
*  true
(  true
)  true
'  true
_  true
<  true
>  true
```

Comment: Is this reg expression correct? Can I switch the characters order in the regular expression like `/[-a-zA-Z0-9!*() ~{}'<>._]/`?
And what is side effect if I remove global flag?